# No Certificate Profile for Permit to Install Found in workspace

Tags: tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I have upgraded from Tizen-IDE 2.4 to Tizen Studio 3.0 to develop on the new Galaxy watch and I have spent many months now trying to permit it to install apps and the Device Manager Keeps throwing the same ERROR

Same as this thread: https://developer.tizen.org/ko/forums/sdk-ide/no-certificate-profil-permit-install-application-was-found-workspace-device-manager?langredirect=1

As it says that it cant find the certificates in the workspace I have played around with where the certs are stored and the where the profile.xml is located and I have uninstalled and installed so very many times. I have tried both Tizen and Samsung certs even though I know you only require Samsung. It looks to me like the Certificate Manager is failing to create a file or put it in the correct spot...

If there is someone out there that has actually faced this issue and knows how to fix it please help! Because its not a simple "clean workspace" or anything like that and I know this because I have done a lot of research before posting here and tried all the basic fixes.....

Comment: The same and no resolution after updating the cert. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been around for 5 years, but searching the internet it's difficult to find an answer to it, so let's go.

- First **open Device Manager**;
- Secondly **open the emulator** you want;
- Then **open the Certificate Manager**, create a **Samsung type certificate** (if you have already created it, create it again);
- At the end of the process you will ask for a **DUID** list, if it is not filled out, do the step below;
- With the **emulator connected** to Device Manager, right-click on it, click on DUID and click on copy and **paste in one of the DUID fields**
  that is requested when creating the certificate.

Everything that is necessary has now been done.

Now, just right-click on the emulator in Device Manager and click on "**Permit to install applications**", and it will automatically accept.